# Joomla component vs plugin vs module

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I im quite new to Joomla and im about to build a website in joomla. I dont have time to read through the whole API and documentation.

I need to develop something which could show food recipes on the client side and an ability to add new recipes.
For the Admin side i need to manage all the stored recipes.

My question is then what will be the best solution module, plugin or component?

Comment: read the docs! at least skim through it.

Comment: `I dont have time to read through the whole API and documentation.` You can't skip this... BTW, 1,) you can do it by storing the recipes as plain articles 2,) if that doesn't suit you, you'll need a component. And probably plugins and modules - depending on how zou want to display zour recipes...

Comment: then try this URL ..ur genius if u just understand all things from a single image without reading according to ur wish http://docs.joomla.org/images/e/e4/Extensions.jpg

Comment: I have skimmed the docs at http://docs.joomla.org. and i didnt find it clear what i need.. Therefore i am questioning. I mean if somebody allready knows how it works why shouldnt i then use his experiences??

Comment: Use WordPress instead, perhaps?

Comment: No thank you @KutF. I have used Wordpress for long time. Now i'm trying something new since Wordpress isn't that good when your systems get too large.. But thanks for your novice recommendation

Comment: ha fair enough. Joomla might suit a large system better than wordpress, but you will need to read all the docs.. eventually. good luck. :-)

Comment: Have you looked in the extensions site an extensions that will do this for you? It really depends ho complex you want to make it. You could indeed just do articles if it's simple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A component

A Joomla component offers extensive (like a shopping cart) and is usually quite complex. An example of a component is the banner manager or CommunityBuilder

A module

Is much smaller than a component functionality wise. You use them to display little bits of information (like who's online) in module positions (eg left, right) on your site. An example of a module is the newsflash module, main menu module, adsense code module etc

A Plugin

Makes small changes/additions to Joomla's functionality. An example of this would be a lightbox plugin when it's installed/enabled it will scan your site for any [lightbox] tags around images and will convert these to an actual lightbox.

[***Read More On Joomla Docs***](http://docs.joomla.org/Extension_types_%28general_definitions%29)

[image]

Comment: So technically i need a component to make the recipe handling part and then i need a module to display alle the recipes?

Comment: yes it really depends on the requirement.

Comment: thanks. I think you just answered my solution :) Merry Christmas